# Revert __toString

Tags: symfony

While uploading a file, I'm trying to check if a directory exists.
If it doesn't exists, then I make the directory.
Directory name basis is the entity name plus is `id` (entity-id)

```
if(!is_dir($this->myDir.'entity-'.$object->getParent())) {
    mkdir($this->myDir.'entity-'.$object->getParent());
}
```

- `myDir` is : `%kernel.root_dir%/../web/upload/myDir/` in `app/config/config.yml`
- `$object` is the object I passed to my function, it contain the data from the submited form.
- getParent() is a __toString of the parent `id`

The problem is that data from the form send the `parent` parameter as a `__toString` of it's `id`
How can I revert this to the parent `id`?

Comment: $object->getParent()->getId() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that getParent() is not `__toString`, but it looks like it, because you try to concatenate it with the 'entity-' string. Therefore you have given object there, so you can access the id with the standard getter (e.g. getId() method)

So the parent object's id should be returned by `$object->getParent()->getId()`

Comment: Indeed, didn't thought about it like that... Thanks!